# updatechildvalues affect navigation

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

When updating child values trough the updateChildValues, when the method executes, pushes the view to a uiTableView without any performSegue or manual segue instruction, here is my code:

```
@IBAction func guardarAnotacionesGenerales(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let elhijo = self.reciboChild
    let nuevaReferencia = self.referencia.child(elhijo)
    let childUpdates = ["AGenerales":"\(self.anotacionesGeneralesTV.text!)"]
    nuevaReferencia.updateChildValues(childUpdates) { (error, referencia) in
        if error != nil {
         }else{
         print("Ya se guardó")   
        }
    }
}
```

just the updateChildValues make this happen.
Pese anyone can help me?? i've been stuck here for a while..

Comment: If you have an .childChanged observer attached the node you are updating,  that will fire when the update occurs. Otherwise there is no correlation between .updateChildValues and a view.

Comment: i used: ref.removeAllObservers() and it worked great¡¡ thank u very much @Jay